# Boost.Test: How to automatically attach debugger (GDB)?

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, gdb, boost-test

When executing Boost tests for a project, I see

```
Test command: ...
Environment variables:
 BOOST_TEST_AUTO_START_DBG=yes
 BOOST_TEST_BUILD_INFO=yes
 BOOST_TEST_CATCH_SYSTEM_ERRORS=yes
 BOOST_TEST_COLOR_OUTPUT=yes
 BOOST_TEST_DETECT_FP_EXCEPTIONS=yes
 BOOST_TEST_LOG_FORMAT=HRF
 BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL=test_suite
 BOOST_TEST_LOG_SINK=stdout
 BOOST_TEST_RANDOM=1
 BOOST_TEST_REPORT_FORMAT=XML
 BOOST_TEST_REPORT_LEVEL=detailed
 BOOST_TEST_REPORT_SINK=...
 BOOST_TEST_RESULT_CODE=yes
...
```

what confirms that the `auto_start_dbg` option is set properly.  Then, for example, the following failure happens:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error: in "...": boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]> >: failed opening file: No such file or directory: iostream error
```

I would have expected to automatically jump into the interactive debugger instance (GDB, in this case) that *traps* this exception.

Are my expectations wrong or is there a misconfiguration on my side?  How do you use this option?

Comment: Hi, I just thought of a better example to make it more convenient to use. Use `assert`. It'll raise a `SIGABRT` if doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are my expectations wrong or is there a misconfiguration on my side? How do you use this option?

Your expectations are wrong. This option is related to signals only. Try dereferencing a NULL pointer and you'll see gdb autostart for you.

### EDIT (2017/02/21)

I just thought about a better example. Use `assert`. Much more convenient to use. It'll raise a `SIGABRT`.